# SQL default constraint W3Schools

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to use a SQL Default Constraint in MS Access 2010?

I know you can do this using the user interface but this has to be done in SQL in a query

On the W3Schools website they have an example of a Default value when creating a website but id doesn't seem to work in Access 2010.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
)
```

Comment: typically you'd do it in [Design View](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/set-a-default-value-for-a-field-or-control-mdb-HP005188852.aspx) but you can do it [programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195837(office.11).aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to do it using SQL in a query window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default value of an Access 2003 field using SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/793043/242520)

Comment: [No.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822825(v=office.14).aspx) "The DEFAULT statement can be executed only through the Access OLE DB provider and ADO. It will return an error message if used through the Access SQL View user interface."

Comment: @ta.speot.is try to run this in Access yourself and see if it works. It doesnt

Comment: Thanks @serakfalcon. If you add this as the answer and noone comes up with a solution I will mark it ac correct

Comment: @WillNZ It worked just fine for me. I enabled ANSI-92 mode first.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use `DEFAULT`, but not through Query View.

By opening the table in Design View, you can alter the `DefaultValue` property of any field.

If you only edit via a form, you can set the `DefaultValue` of the linked control, which will have a similar effect (but direct queries will not cause this value to be inserted).

It is not possible to do it via Query View (source:[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822825(v=office.14).aspx))

But it is possible using ADODB. (from [How to set the default value of an Access 2003 field using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792059/how-to-set-the-default-value-of-an-access-2003-field-using-sql/793043#793043) )

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("CREATE TABLE Persons " & _
    "(P_Id int NOT NULL, " & _
    " LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL, " & _
    " FirstName varchar(255), " & _
    " Address varchar(255), " & _
    " City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes' )
```

Comment: If you enable ANSI-92 mode it works just fine.